# How to retrieve multiple contacts with single REST call

Tags: rest-api, bulk-api

I am getting 20 contact ID from getUpdated.Now I need information for each of these 20 contacts.It seems costly to request each contact through a REST url.Is there any way how I can query multiple contacts through 1 url? 
 Is the bulk api designed for this?If so,how does the url looks like?I assue it is a REST url too.

Comment: Everything you need to know about the bulk api here: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/ - You could also creat your own rest endpoint to return the data you need. Otherwise the REST API is single record only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the the `/sobjects/<type>/<id>` endpoint you'll need to switch to the query endpoint (`/query/?q=<query>`) to make use of this.

SOQL Supports using an [IN operator](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm) here. If your current query looks like, say, `SELECT id, name, ownerId FROM Contact WHERE Id = 'someId'` you could use IN as:
`SELECT id, name, ownerId FROM Contact WHERE Id IN ('firstId', 'secondId')`

Having one item in the parentheses is fine, and works just like equals then. You also can use this multi-item syntax with equals (`=`) but using the IN operator makes your intentions more clear to future readers so I always recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your APEX class and then expose that as a REST resource .Let me draft a simple example to help you with

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/retrieveContacts/*')
 global with sharing class MyRestResource {

  @HttpPost
     global static list<Contact> doPost(List<Id> lstcontactId) {
      return [Select id,name,fax,Phone,Email from Contact where Id IN:lstcontactId];
     }
 }
```

> This will create a REST END POINT at /services/apexrest/retrieveContacts .You will need to input array of Contact Ids to this webservice